# wkhtmltopdf not working on server javascript

Tags: javascript, meteor, ubuntu-16.04, wkhtmltopdf, digital-ocean

I am developing an application using Meteor js in which I need to generate a pdf so i have used 'wkhtmltopdf' npm module and also install the wkhtmltopdf command line tool through following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

**Server Info:**

```
Linux ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 4.4.0-72-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:07:41 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

wkhtmltopdf version install on server: 0.12.2.4
```

When i am trying to generating the pdf on local machine, everything working well but on server(digital ocean), it throws error /bin/blash command not found.

I have also tried to change the path of wkhtmltopdf like below:

```
wkhtmltopdf.command = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Same above errow throws in this case.

**When i try to test wkhtmltopdf on server using below command:**

```
wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com google.pdf
```

error throw: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

Please guide me, how i can make wkhtmltopdf working on server.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First link from Google by searching your error text: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192642/wkhtmltopdf-qxcbconnection-could-not-connect-to-display

It contains solutions to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have followed link: https://codingexplained.com/dev-ops/installing-wkhtmltopdf-on-ubuntu-14-04-and-16-04. and the error is resolved but now application throwing Error: **/bin/bash: wkhtmltopdf: command not found

wkhtmltopdf exited with code 127**